# Blu-Ray writer cancels writing when buffer is underrun

Tags: windows-7, burning, blu-ray

Recently I've installed ASUS BW-12B1LT BD Writer (SATA). After multiple trials I've still 0% of success in writing BD Data Discs. [I had not such problems with ATA DVD writer connected to this system]

I use PHILIPS BD-R 1-6x speed and included software: CyberLink Media Suite 8 and Power2Go (on Windows 7 64-bit SP1).

If buffer is underrun BD writing is canceled and disc is broken. Why? Protection was set to on.

CyberLink does not give me any option to choose slower speed than 4x.
My data is on nVidia soft-RAID (on the same controller that BD writer).

Please give me some clues.

- Should undderrun protection to act like this?
- Is it possible to force slower speed at Power2Go.
- Is something wrong with nVidia controller when it's in RAID mode and underrun protection does not work then?
- Can you recommend free but reliable software for BD data disc writing?

Comment: Probably just stating the obvious: BD requires more processing and i/o speed than dvd/cd.  Is your system fast enough?  Providing a few other details of your hardware might help someone to answer you.  Are all your drivers at the latest versions?  Does your system device manager show any errors?